# 7z format compression

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compression, 7zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create 7-Zip archives with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net)

I'm looking for ways to do compression and decompression in 7z format via code in VB.NET and C#. Is there any library or .Net code for this purpose?

I know there are GZipStream and DeflateStream in .Net but I want 7z format for better compression ratio.

Comment: You may find this [interesting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx)

Comment: Upvote for all responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)?

EDIT:

Thanks to dtb for mentioning

> LZMA SDK contains only an implementation of the LZMA compression method, not classes for reading for writing 7z files

There is [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) project that is open source wrapper for 7-zip to do this work.

> **Project Description**
>
> Managed 7-zip library written in C# that provides data (self-)extraction and compression (all 7-zip formats are supported). It wraps 7z.dll or any compatible one and makes use of LZMA SDK.

Comment: It's noteworthy that the LZMA SDK contains only an implementation of the LZMA compression method, not classes for reading for writing 7z files.

Answer (score 4):

[Use the official SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) :)

Answer (score 3):

I belive 7zip provides an sdk which has a c# project in it.

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html