# SevenZSharp Decode with password

Tags: c#, .net, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I work with SevenZSharp from [here](http://7zsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/10305)

for Decode file I use:

```
CompressionEngine.Current.Decoder.DecodeIntoDirectory(@"D:\target\host_update.7z", @"D:\target");
```

But I don't have information how to decode .7z file with password!? Please, help me. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [extract 7zip in C# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994477/extract-7zip-in-c-sharp-code)

Answer (score 2):

To use "SevenZipSharp" which DOES support passwords and a wide range of formats...

Import SevenZipSharp.dll into .Net project references...

Place "7zx64.dll" and "7z.dll" into the directory...

Then use this code to check the pass and extract if correct..

**code**

```
Imports SevenZip
Public Class FrmMain
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn1.Click

    ''Call to set DLL depending on processor type''
    If Environment.Is64BitProcess Then
        SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath("7zx64.dll")
    Else
        SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath("7z.dll")
    End If

    ''Set Destination of extraction''
    Dim DestDir = Application.StartupPath

    Try
        ''Check file with password''
        Dim Ext As New SevenZipExtractor(Tb1.Text, Tb2.Text)

        If Ext.Check() Then
            ''Extract files to destination''
            Ext.BeginExtractArchive(DestDir)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

By the look of the source code of SevenZSharp, it does not support password protected files.

[Here's something else that might help you from codeplex](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx). It seem to have an interface called `ICryptoGetTextPassword` that you might be able to use if the 7z is password protected.

**Edit**

With a bit further look at SevenZipSharp it seems that it should support password protected archives accroding to their project page ( http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/ ):

> - Encryption and passwords are supported.

You need to download the latest code from [Codeplex](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/59007) and build it yourself, in it you will have a class called `SevenZipExtractor` where you have the following constructor:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of SevenZipExtractor class.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="archiveFullName">The archive full file name.</param>
/// <param name="password">Password for an encrypted archive.</param>
public SevenZipExtractor(string archiveFullName, string password)
    : base(password)
{
    Init(archiveFullName);
}
```

**Note** this is not the same as Seven7Sharp, this is SevenZipSharp, but it works with `7z`.

Comment: I find other way - I download SDK from here:[link]http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html maybe somebody has experience with it - how I can decode file with key with SDK?(I sucessful added SDK to my project)

Comment: @koder_mooder, I've updated my answer with another library that you can use that is called SevenZipSharp and not Seven7Sharp, I hope this will work out for you!

Comment: I added project by your link and found SevenZipExtractor.cs with method:SevenZipExtractor(string archiveFullName, string password)

Comment: I need to add dlls to my project?

Comment: @koder_mooder, you need to compile the project, open the solution and then Press F5, then in your other project you reference the DLLs that you just compiled.

Comment: I add SevenZipSharp.dll, but can't add 7z.dll.

Comment: It gives me: Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: DLL file does not exist.

Comment: SevenZipExtractor c = new SevenZipExtractor(@"D:\target\web_update.7z", "123");
            c.ExtractArchive(@"D:\target");

Comment: Did that last code work out for you? You don't need to reference 7-zip library, just add a reference to SevenZipSharp and you should be OK, or at least add a reference to all the dlls in the output folder.

Comment: last code give me: Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: DLL file does not exist.

Comment: in debug folder it gives me just 2 dlls

Comment: Copy 7z.dll to the output directory of your new application as well, it should work.