# How to extract a single file from a 7-ZIP archive in C#?

Tags: c#, zip, extract, 7zip

I Have a 7-Zip file that contains many files inside. How can I extract one special file inside without extracting the whole archive?

Is it possible to list all the files and choose one to get in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first off all must use `7-zip` stand alone console.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994477/extract-7zip-in-c-sharp-code) post can help you.

then in console you can filter files by using filters section

```
7za.exe x archive.zip -o outputdir *.xml *.pdb *.exe *.ocx *.dll -r
```

or simple `7za.exe x archive.zip -o outputdir a.xml -r`