# How to decompress a 7z archive with C# .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, 7zip, lzma

I want my app to use files from a .7z file.

I have found some explanations of [how to decompress a 7z file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646328/how-to-use-the-7z-sdk-to-compress-and-decompress-a-file). However, they are all about a case I have not yet encountered in the wild: An archive that decompresses to a single file. I would expect a .7z archive to decompress to an arbitrary amount of files, possibly in arbitrary subfolders.

It seems like it would be possible to do this by [including the whole 7zip application and then running that in a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994477/extract-7zip-in-c-sharp-code). However, that seems like unnecessary extra steps, considering there's an [official LZMA SDK](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html). Also, it leads to problems concerning cross compatibility.

So, how can I unpack a .7z archive into a given folder, using  in C# (.NET 3.5)?

## Additional info from comments

"*Please show the code that isn't working.*"
Well, at the moment I'm using the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8605828/5900626) on another question. However, I'm *expecting* that to not do what I want - `output` (just like `input`) is a `FileStream`, so it's clear that this only creates one file.
It shows that `Decoder` is the class doing the decompressing, but it doesn't have a method that works with e.g. a `DirectoryInfo`, a `string` path or anything like that - it's all *one file in, one file out*. Every info I found on using the SDK does this very same thing; I haven't found a single one extracting an archive to several files.

Comment: Is there some reason not to just Process.Start() 7z.exe with the command line arguments you are looking for or are you looking for source that understands the 7z archive?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Either include the 3 required files (7za.exe, 7az.dll, & 7zxa.dll) in your project and launch it with the `Process` class, or use the LZMA SDK library as you noted above. What specific issue are you running into? Please show the code that isn't working.

Comment: @RufusL Thank you, for your comment. I want to avoid the .exe solution because **A)** It's more crude, but at the same time more complex in the sense that more things that can go wrong. A missing file would become a runtime- instead of a compiler error etc. **B)** This is to be used in Unity3D, which can be built for Windows, Linux, iOS, Android, PS4, WebGL and many more. 
I added the info about "code that isn't working" to the question itself.

Comment: @ThorynHawley  In short, "cross compatibility". I elaborated a little bit in my previous comment addressed at RufusL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come to the following conclusion:

**Decompressing a .7z archive into a folder is not a feature provided by the C# LZMA SDK.**

I'm afraid I have not found any hard evidence, like a blog post directly stating it.

However, I have found [a description of the `.7z` file format](http://www.romvault.com/Understanding7z.pdf). This description did not provide enough technical detail to craft a working solution, but it contained certain facts about the format:

> In this section I will explain how the previous example is stored in the data Structured[...]
>
> First up is the ​Header ​this contains just two variables: ​FileInfo​ and ​StreamsInfo.
>
> FileInfo​ is probably the easiest structure to understand. It contains the name of each file in the 7z and a couple of other flags defining if the file is actually a directory or if the file is an empty file.

This structure is not reflected in the code of the C# SDK as far as I can see. That, combined with the information that the `Decoder.Code()` methods do not work with a directory path or more than one output `Stream` is a strong indicator.

So it seems that the C# part of the LZMA SDK only handles en- and decryption of a single file, or "Compressed Stream" as it is called in the linked document. The `.7z` archive format then counts as a separate format, which is ultimately a structure to contain an arbitrary number of compressed streams.

These streams can actually be combined in, again, arbitrary ways; e.g. an archive can contain files A and B compressed with LZMA, then add file C to the mix and compress it again with another algorithm. That makes decompressing a `.7z` archive more complex, which makes it even more of a pity that this functionality is not provided in the SDK.

Comment: One would thing a project existed wrapping the LZMA SDK to handle .7z etc...did anyone found one? One which is maintained?
There seem to be  few on nuget but which the is the best?