# Troubleshoot azure appservice - Out of memory exception with huge data

Tags: c#, azure

Please provide your opinion for best suited App service plan for Function APP.

I am running a .net webjob on azure app service in production environment.  This webjob reads .json file from azure blob and store into sql database.  Some of my the files includes data up to 2 GB.

I am getting out of memory exceptions in azure appservice, however it worked absolutely fine in development machine.

I would like to try couple of options from azure side.

1. Converting  webjob to Azure function which will autoscale as per requirement.
2. Currently I am using Premium v2 P3V2. Below is the picture of app service plan

[image]

I have already done some code optimization as shown below however it doesn't help

```
using (var zipBlobFileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(zipBlobFileStream);
    await zipBlobFileStream.FlushAsync();
    zipBlobFileStream.Position = 0;

   
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(zipBlobFileStream))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            if (entry.Length == 0) continue; // Skip if entry has no content

            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
            {
                // Move to the start of the array
                while (jsonReader.Read() && jsonReader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray) ;

                // Read each object in the array
                while (jsonReader.Read() && jsonReader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
                {
                    // Deserialize JSON object directly from the stream
                    var messageItem= serializer.Deserialize<MessageItem>(jsonReader);

                   
                    var DataItems = new DataItems 
                    {                            
                        items = new List<DataItem> { DataItems }
                    };

                    result.Add(MessageItems);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the disk filesystem, instead of doing everything in-memory...

Comment: For example, save that `.zip` archive to disk and use a separate program (e.g. `7z`) to extract it back to disk. I see you're already using `JsonReader` to stream the content which is good.

Comment: Also, see if you can catch your program after it's passed some threshold and take a memory-dump and see where all that memory is going using VS' `.dmp` analyzer.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the answer. Does 7z zip will be working in Azure appservice environment

Comment: `7z.exe` works fine in Azure App Services for all of my projects that use it. It's _waaaaaay_ faster than .NET's `ZipArchive` (and multi-threaded too). Just make sure you're extracting to `%TMP%` (`C:\local\temp`) and not anywhere in your persisted storage (as persisted-storage is much slower and shared by other instances).

Comment: @Dai Its fine in dev machine. How does it store in disk with azure appservices
   // Use 7z to extract the zip file
    Process.Start("7z", $"x \"{zipFilePath}\" -o\"{extractedFolderPath}\" -y").WaitForExit();

Comment: Something like that, yes. BTW, are these zip files coming from untrusted sources? If not, you will need to watch for directory-traversal attacks (e.g. a zip file containing a file named `foo\..\..\..\..\lol.txt`)

Comment: @Dai It trounout an error - $exception {"The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."} System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Comment: @Dai 7zip is not supported with windows application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190767/how-to-decompress-a-7z-archive-with-c-sharp-net-3-5

Comment: That linked QA is entirely irrelevant: it has absolutely nothing to do with my comments about using `7z.exe` as a command-line program to perform extraction out-of-proc. What you linked-to is about using the LZMA library in-proc for handling `archive.7z` files (which are not `.zip` files either).

Comment: You can set DOTNET_GCHeapHardLimit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector#heap-limit) to test your process on your workstation with limited memory. If the environment variable is not set, the runtime will infer limits based on the environment, eg linux container / cgroup limits.

Comment: @Dai & Jeremy I would say to insert huge amount of data. FunctionApps are good option. Now memory time out issue is resolved. I am facing another issue while reading message from service queue, lock expires in 5 mins and I need atleast  20 mins to insert 3.5 mi records. Any clue

Comment: It shouldn't take 20 minutes to insert 3.5m records (is this SQL Server?) - heck, I can insert ~10m * ~2KiB-sized rows _from my home internet connection_ directly into Azure SQL in under ~2 minutes. My point being, you likely have _a lot_ of room for optimization there...

Comment: @Dai The problem here is I can't use entity framework since I need to add some additional columns in table apart from the data I am getting In file

Comment: @Techiemanu ...who said anything about Entity Framework? (and EF _won't_ help you with fast inserts anyway). Aren't you using `SqlBulkCopy` or `bcp`?

Comment: @Dai How do you store 10 mi records is it list or data table? Do you write all 10 mi. records at one shot in DB using bulckcopy?. Here us my code

using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))  bulk.DestinationTableName = "item"; bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 1800;bulk.WriteToServer(dt);

Comment: @Dai In order to avoid memory issue, I am reading records in batches and insert to DB in loop

Comment: I used `SqlBulkCopy` using synthesized data.

Comment: This is crazy.   await dbContext.BulkInsertAsync(Items); It take 2 mins to insert 300k records. Its really insane. How can you insert 10 mi in less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out solution of the given problem after some trial and error . I would like to thank @Dai for his valuble suggestions. Here is my solution

1. Converting to Azure functionApp helped to scale application automatically and out of meomory ecpetion has gone.
2. I am able to insert around 4 million record in 5 mins with below code.

   using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionstring))
   {
   await connection.OpenAsync();
   bulkCopy.TableName = "MyTable"
   bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10000;
   bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
   await bulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(table);
   }