# How do I create 7-Zip archives containing multiple files with .NET?

Tags: c#, 7zip, lzma

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net?answertab=active#tab-top) in this post it is mentioned how to Compress and Decompress files using LZMA SDK. 
Here is the Code :

```
public static void CompressFileLZMA(string inFile, string outFile)
{
    Int32 dictionary = 1 << 23;
    Int32 posStateBits = 2;
    Int32 litContextBits = 3; // for normal files
    // UInt32 litContextBits = 0; // for 32-bit data
    Int32 litPosBits = 0;
    // UInt32 litPosBits = 2; // for 32-bit data
    Int32 algorithm = 2;
    Int32 numFastBytes = 128;

    string mf = "bt4";
    bool eos = true;
    bool stdInMode = false;


    CoderPropID[] propIDs =  {
        CoderPropID.DictionarySize,
        CoderPropID.PosStateBits,
        CoderPropID.LitContextBits,
        CoderPropID.LitPosBits,
        CoderPropID.Algorithm,
        CoderPropID.NumFastBytes,
        CoderPropID.MatchFinder,
        CoderPropID.EndMarker
    };

    object[] properties = {
        (Int32)(dictionary),
        (Int32)(posStateBits),
        (Int32)(litContextBits),
        (Int32)(litPosBits),
        (Int32)(algorithm),
        (Int32)(numFastBytes),
        mf,
        eos
    };

    using (FileStream inStream = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Encoder encoder = new SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Encoder();
            encoder.SetCoderProperties(propIDs, properties);
            encoder.WriteCoderProperties(outStream);
            Int64 fileSize;
            if (eos || stdInMode)
                fileSize = -1;
            else
                fileSize = inStream.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                outStream.WriteByte((Byte)(fileSize >> (8 * i)));
            encoder.Code(inStream, outStream, -1, -1, null);
        }
    }

}

public static void DecompressFileLZMA(string inFile, string outFile)
{
    using (FileStream input = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (FileStream output = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create))
        {
            SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Decoder decoder = new SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Decoder();

            byte[] properties = new byte[5];
            if (input.Read(properties, 0, 5) != 5)
                throw (new Exception("input .lzma is too short"));
            decoder.SetDecoderProperties(properties);

            long outSize = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                int v = input.ReadByte();
                if (v < 0)
                    throw (new Exception("Can't Read 1"));
                outSize |= ((long)(byte)v) << (8 * i);
            }
            long compressedSize = input.Length - input.Position;

            decoder.Code(input, output, compressedSize, outSize, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to Compress and Decompress Multiple Files with the SDK.
What should I change in the code to get the best results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last I decided to use [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/). It has simple classes to Compress and Decompress Multiple Files, Single Files or bytes or Streams.