# Integrating 7-zip library in to a C#.NET application

Tags: c#, .net, compression, 7zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create 7-Zip archives with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net)

How can we integrate 7-zip archiving library in a C#.NET application. I am working on an application that need to have an extraction utility for stored zip files, for which I guess 7Zip's DLL will be the best.

Can any one tell me how can I use it to integrate into my application. My need is to open a Fileopen dialog on a button click->browse for the zip file->Then extract it and save the files somewhere.

I tried using SevenZipSharp Library, here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor.SetLibraryPath(@"F:\PARADOX\WFAST\WFAST\Res\7z.dll");
        SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor ext = new SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\stitch.zip");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Stitch");
        ext.BeginExtractArchive("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Stitch");

    }
```

But get error: `Can not load 7-zip library or internal COM error! Message: failed to load library.`

Comment: You may wish to reconsider your terminology in future - you're not "implementing" a 7-zip library - you're integrating the existing 7-zip library into your application. The way you've worded it at the moment makes it sound like you'd be writing the archiving code yourself in a compatible way...

Comment: You may also wish to reconsider using StackOverflow, since it's clear nobody here has read your question to the end nor had any hands-on experience with SevenZipSharp. But hey, at least FIVE separate people took the time to mark your question as a duplicate. That was obviously the best response we could have had.

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for 7zip, of course just use 7 zip. I don't really understand how there could be a question to that end. Why you would need to wrap it in some .NET app is unclear, since 7zip has both a nice gui and command line interface.

If on the other hand you actually want to write a simple .NET application that can handle compressed files, you might start with the System.IO.Compression namespace, which has been part of the .NET standard library for a number of releases. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx

Comment: But ZipFile, ZipArchive only available in .NET 4.5 or later

Comment: Can't use it, as the program on which I am working will make a zip file that can be found corrupt by .NET's `System.IO.Compression`. The resultant zip file would be a kind of encrypted file that can be extracted by 7zip easily, but not with .NET's compression library.

Comment: Ok, then take my first suggestion and use 7zip, then pipe back in. That is clearly the best solution, as suggested in the duplicate mentioned above. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx if you need help with that also.