# Reboot Windows from within a service

Tags: c#, windows

Is there a way to reboot Windows from within a service (Server 2008, Server 2012)?  I've tried:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe /c shutdown -f -r -t 0")
```

To no avail.  I've looked at solutions here:

[How to shut down the computer from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102567/how-to-shutdown-the-computer-from-c-sharp)

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215139/reboot-machine-from-a-c-wpf-app

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/shut-down-restart-log-off-and-forced-log-off-system-using-C-Sharp/

and the machine just doesn't want to reboot.

When I run the command from the command line, it works.

```
cmd.exe /c shutdown -f -r -t 0
```

or even

```
shutdown -f -r -t 0
```

Nothing happens when run from within the service.  I even modified it to run:

```
c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c c:\\windows\\system32\\shutdown.exe -f -r -t 0
```

And same result, nothing happens.  Again when I run from the command line, it reboots properly.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606426/process-start-does-not-work-when-called-from-windows-service

Comment: What happens when you execute this from the service?

Comment: take care of the application path. Your service/app may not find cmd.exe or shutdown.exe

Comment: Hi Xaruth and Ron, I updated accordingly.  Tested with path and it still doesnt work.  Thanks

Comment: Is your process running as admin?

Comment: Sorry Ron, let me test with your method...

Comment: What happens if you P/Invoke `ExitWindowsEx`?

Comment: Ron: ProcessStartInfo method did not work.  Roger, code example please?

Comment: Which user are you using for the service? Does it have machine rights? Are you connected to a domain? Does that domain have user policies that might affect a service's ability to restart a machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that because a window service has no GUI ... that it cannot run a command prompt.

Look into a win32 API solution ... like ExitWindowsEx() or InitiateSystemShutdown or shutdown

Comment: Thanks Marc, do you have a code example or link to share?

Comment: Tried this one, didn't work.  http://debugmode.net/2010/05/18/shut-down-restart-log-off-and-forced-log-off-system-using-c/

Comment: Worked after using the token adjuster found in the solution here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726116/when-using-exitwindowsex-logoff-works-but-shutdown-and-restart-do-not

Comment: No sweat Marc, I found a code sample in the link in my previous comment.  I marked yours as the answer.  Have a great day!

Comment: I don't think it's GUI related.  `shutdown.exe` can be run directly via `CreateProcess` as a `DETACHED_PROCESS` (no console window), which works for me on a remote shell running in session 0 (Windows 7 service). I don't know why cmd.exe even factors into this.  If you run `shutdown.exe` as a non-detached process the system will create a console window for it that has nothing to do with `cmd.exe`. The process for the console window is `conhost.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
Process myPro = new Process()  
myPro.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
myPro.StartInfo.Arguments = “/c shutdown –f –r –t 0”;
myPro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myPro.CreateNoWindow = true;
myPro.Start();
```

Also where is your cmd.exe file?  If its not ran out of the same directory that your application is running from? You may need to provide a pathway to point to the cmd.exe file.

example..

```
myPro.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\desktop\myStuff\cmd.exe";
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Marc, this would have worked except it's running as a service and cannot run a command prompt.  Per the question above I also tried setting explicit paths.  Marc Johnston's solution below was the correct one, though yours would be appropriate for an app that can spawn a command prompt.  Thanks!