# Zip multiple files using 7zip.exe in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, process, 7zip

I have to zip multiple files together using 7zip.exe. I have paths of two files say file1 and file2. I append the two paths using the following.
string filetozip = file1+ "\"" + file2+" "; and do the below

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Freedom\7-Zip\7z.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

       proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("    a -tzip \"{0}\" \"{1}\" -mx=9 -mem=AES256 -p\"{2}\"    ", destZipFile, filetozip , zipPassword);
        proc.Start();

        proc.WaitForExit();

        if (proc.ExitCode != 0)
        {
           throw new Exception("Error Zipping Data File : " + proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

filetozip  is passed as an argument above. The above code does not work properly. I am getting proc.ExitCode=1. Which is the right way to append the file paths.Is string filetozip = file1+ "\"" + file2+" "; the right way? I can have one or more files. What is the separator used?

Comment: Do you have to use 7zip.exe?  As of .Net 3.0, a zip class is built in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis

Comment: I am suggested to use 7zip only.Please let me know how to use.

Comment: Yes I have 7zip.exe @SteveWellens

Comment: I go the above code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net  answered by @lifestylebyatom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line that you want to create looks like

[image]

plus the required switches (arguments quoted and space delimited).

[String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) are some coding things that may be helpful