# 7Zip Over Network

Tags: 7zip

Nowadays I've a process that copies file by file. This is taking a lot of time.

Thought about the following solution:

- Compress all files in a **serverA** and then copy the zip file to **serverB**;
- Decompress this file in **serverB**;

Is there anyway to decompress this file by command line after the file is copied?

Comment: Just an FYI, the [.net] tag is used for Microsoft's .NET framework rather than network communication questions.

Comment: I've added this tag, because I wanted to post a .net code of tis implementation.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. I believe the [zipfile class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netcore-3.1) should help you with that.

Comment: Do you know if running 7zip command to decompress file over network, runs the decompression locally or remotely?

Comment: Well if you run `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` on Server A, use whatever FTP you are using to pass the zip archive and then run `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory` on Server B it will do the compression/decompression locally and only pass the zip archive between them.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't run locally on Server A?  ZipFile dl works with 7zip too?

Comment: The builtin `ZipFile` class only works in the standard zip format. [There are other non-standard libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net) that could allow you to specifically use the 7z format if that is a hard requirement, including the [LZMA SDK provided by the 7-zip creators](https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)