# Trying to use 7z compression in my code, but when it executes. Nothing is created

Tags: c#, 7zip

I am trying to use 7-zip in my code for mutiple gig folders. I tried to use the following code, but all it does is execute and nothing is created.  No error codes and in that the folder I was trying to zip is 7 gig. It ran way to quick.

```
string strZipName = strInputFolder + ".7z";
string strWhatToZip = strInputFolder + "\\*";
Process p = Process.Start("7z", string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" a -t7z", @strZipName, @strWhatToZip));
p.WaitForExit();
```

I tried this code both with the @ and without, and both times nothing happened.  Here is a screen shot of the debug session I ran, and if you look in the lower left corner. You can see the values of the variables.
[image]

I then installed the nutg package aspose.zip, which actually did create a 7z file. But, it did not even come close to adding everything in the folder to the zip file before it completed.  Again, there were no error messages.

Here is the complete code I was trying to use.

```
 class ArchiveFolders
 {
     public void Run7Zip(string strInputFolder, string strOutputFolder)
     {
        try
         {
             using (var archive = new SevenZipArchive(new SevenZipEntrySettings(new SevenZipLZMACompressionSettings())))
             {
                 Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                 archive.CreateEntries(strInputFolder);
                 archive.Save("d:\\7Z_ManyFilesToCompress.7z");
                 Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
             }
             //7z a -t7z ".\Sadr - Narrow band filter.7z" ".\Sadr - Narrow band filter\*"
            /* string strZipName = strInputFolder + ".7z";
             string strWhatToZip = strInputFolder + "\\*";
             Process p = Process.Start("7z", string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\" a -t7z", @strZipName, @strWhatToZip));
             p.WaitForExit();*/
         }
        catch (Exception ex) 
         {
             MessageBox.Show("archive failed");
         }

         MessageBox.Show("Data Folder has been archived ");
     }
 }
```

To be honest, I would rather use the 7z executable already installed on my machine.  But I am not locked into that.

Any and all help is most appreciated.

Comment: "To be honest, I would rather use the 7z executable already installed on my machine" that's what `Process.Start("7z"...` does. Usually the executable is called 7za.exe. You may want to use an absolute path to the exe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create 7-Zip archives with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net)

Comment: I think you also might have the arguments mixed up and you aren't using the output folder name. Should be  something like `Process.Start("7z", $"a -t7z \"{Path.Combine(strOutputFolder, Path.GetFileName(strInputFolder) + ".7z")}\" \"{strWhatToZip}\"");`

Comment: I finally used this code: string strWorkName = Path.GetFileName(strInputFolder);
strWorkName = strWorkName + ".7z";
string[] strWorkPath = { strOutputFolder, strWorkName };
var strfullPath = Path.Combine(strWorkPath);
string strWhatToZip = strInputFolder + "\\*";
Process.Start("7z", $"a -t7z \"{strfullPath}\" \"{strWhatToZip}\"");                                    For what ever reason, I am not being given the option of what resolved my problem.   Wish I could mark it, but I don't see the check mark next to the post.  Thank you everyone for the help.